# UbuntuOne not synching

Tags: ubuntu-one

UbuntuOne worked and all my folders were synced (~8 GB). Currently UbuntuOne shows only 4.7GB synced.

Then I had to re-install Ubuntu from scratch (11.10). Since then I cannot mark folders as "Synchronize this Folder".
I Right-click on my folder in my  home folder and choose "UbuntoOne > Synchronize this folder". But it does not do anything.
It does not show any of the sync status available 
"Not synchronized"
"Synchronizing"
"Synchronized"
nor the correspondent symbols either after that. I tried on several folders and .

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I managed to by pass that by cutting everything and pasting it in an other folder and do the opposite manipulation. Then it synchronises. But that would be cool to not have to do that

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It seems that Ubuntu One have somewhat like a "Filewatcher event" and start syncing only when a file is created / modified.